# How do I install pgfpages package?

Tags: packages, miktex, pgfpages

I want to print out handout for my beamer presentation. I am trying to get `pgfpages` package from MiKTeX package Manager without success? Can you please help?

Comment: Restart the MiKTeX package manager.  Check the given log file, if the error is still there. Please show the resulting error in your question ... Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: pgfpages is part of the pgf-package.

Comment: Using `\documentclass[handout]{beamer}` and printing using the default Windows print dialog with `multiple pages per sheet` could also be a solution.